# external domain to godaddy ultimate shared hosting

Tags: dns, hosting, ping

i have provided the following details to a domain registrar , my shared hosting account ip address, and the main domain's two DNS records which i copied from dns manager. i have added the domain in the hosted domains section and assigned a folder with a blank page in it. the domain is www.mahala.co.zw . i have gone to domaintools.com and looked up the domain and it shows its registered and returns the correct DNS records but when i visit the site it does not resolve. is there anything i missed on the godaddy side before i go back to the registrar. Please help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best way to add an external domain to GoDaddy Ultimate Hosting is as so:

1. Add the domain manually in the domain section of your hosting. There is a section where it says "add external domain"
2. Wait about 2 hours and your domain will show as part of your domain list
3. Click the domain and go to the bottom of the page and then copy the now self generated DNS records (2 of them)
4. Apply these to the place you bought your domain (pointing your domain to these DNS records)
5. Go to your GoDaddy hosting, log in to the hosting account you want to use, go to hosted domains, and it should auto fill when you add the new domain name to the the list
6. You are done ! Good luck, God speed because GoDaddy is the worst when it comes to this process; I guarantee you none of their support section notes have such a step by step remotely close to this one I have written.

Comment: Thank you! About step 1: at this date, I had to add my external domain in Godaddy in _manage hosting > **Hosted domains**_ (in manage domains was not possible). After some minutes, the external domain appeared in _manage domains_, and I could see the DNS records.

Comment: Its changed slightly now in the new interface. You have to go to Domain Manager then on one of the top menus "DNS", click "Add DNS Hosting".